# Generate geometries from each intersection and apply aggregation to row

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to figure out how to use PostGIS (since I have my polygons stored there already) to generate a set of nonoverlapping polygons.

The source table has two columns (`geometry` and `occurences`), `geometry` is always a valid polygon, `occurences` is an integer.

The polygons in the table can overlap. For all the overlapping regions (there can generally be more than 2 intersecting polygons) I would like to generate a new polygon (as with `ST_Intersection`) **AND** apply an aggregation to the `occurences` column (MIN/MAX/AVG would be enough)

I can find pairs of overlaps by using ST_Intersects and handle the pairs, but I have trouble reducing multiple intersections.

In the following example, the 3 source rows would actually end up being 7 separate polygons (imagine the circle is actually a POLYGON geometry), the `occurences` then would be averaged from all interesecting polygons in each case.

[image]